# NSURL not instantiating properly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am new to IPhone developing.

I have got very strange issue with NSURL which is driving me crazy. I want to instantiate NSURL object to use it in loading image. But instantiation never happens in proper way. It always says my url in invalid.

Basically I use code like below:

```
NSString *str = @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

but I also have tried a lot of different modifications (with CFStringRef + CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes and so on). All of them are not working for me. In debugger url is set to "Invalid".

What it could be? I don't think this is algorithmic or environment issue. It could be about some settings?

Have anyone any idea of what happens?

Comment: `NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];` works just fine.  What's your *actual* code?

Comment: (my comment above has an `http://` in it, but the filter changed it into a link)

Answer (score 3):

Your string isn't escaped properly - you should do it like this:

```
NSString *str = @"http://google.com";
NSString *escStr = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                              NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escStr];
```

Comment: This code makes the same error. When I look in debugger: _urlString parameter of url is "Invalid". And next use of url raises exception.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using that actual code or just code "like" it? That method will return nil if you don't feed it a valid string with everything escaped properly.

Comment: The exact code are:

1) native to NSString escaping:

    NSString *str = @"http://google.com";
    NSString *escaped = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escaped];

and 2) CFStringRef escaping:

    NSString *str = @"http://google.com";
    CFStringRef escaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=+$,", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)escaped];

Both are failing.